# How to interpret the contents of /proc/bus/pci/devices?

Tags: pci, linux

The first few fields of 'cat /proc/bus/pci/devices' are understandable.

**Field 1 - BusDevFunc

Field 2 - Vendor Id + Device Id

Field 3 - Interrupt Line

Field 4 - BAR 0**   
and the rest of the BAR registers (0 - 5) after that.

After the BAR registers are printed out, what are the other fields? Specifically, what PCI configuration space registers(offsets) are printed out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this question has been answered here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790637/how-to-interpret-the-contents-of-proc-bus-pci-devices